# Multiple thread access to Excel

Tags: c#, multithreading, excel

I have two methods, method1, method2, both have lock(App) where App is a static instance in the same class.

***App is a static instance in a shared project Helper***

```
void method1()
{
    lock(Helper.App)
    { 
       ExcelApp.FormulaCell.AddComments(errMsg);
    }
}

    void method2()
    {
        lock(Helper.App)
        {  
           //plot data (an 2-D array) to cells
           var dataRng = ExcelApp.CurrentSheet.Cells(Formulacell.Row + 1, Formulacell.Column + 1);
           dataRng = dataRng.get_Resize(n, m);
           dataRng.Value2 = data;
        }
    }
```

method1, method2 are called by many threads. 
I want at one time only method1 or method2 run
The issue is they seem not.
in method1 & method2, I plot some data to Excel, I get Exception

> Name:COMException
>   Message:Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472

I googled and find the exception is caused by Excel Application is not ready.
There is no UI gesture, so I conclude the exception is caused by the two methods try to write to Excel at the same time.

Comment: Are you currently experiencing `method1()` and `method2()` being run at the same time?

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't figure out what the problem is. What have you coded so far? Are you getting any error?

Comment: What you have there should work. What problems are you getting?

Comment: Using `lock(App)` produce a compile error because `App` is a type, not not a `Type` object.  For future reference, you should post the compile error that you are getting when you pose questions like this.

Comment: @JonSenchyna: You're assuming that App is a type but the OP specifies in the OP that `App is a static instance' in that class.

Comment: "App is a static instance in a shared project" Are there two or more executables running at the same time?

Comment: @PaulSasik: I missed that portion of the first sentence, and the rest of the places where it is mentioned were not added yet.  Thank you for pointing that out, rather than simply down-voting and leaving me clueless as to why.  I have removed my answers as they are no longer applicable.

Comment: I've updated title as issue seem to be with using Excel from multiple threads, not with locking/threading code itself (also it may be good idea to update sample showing some 1-2 lines where you actually do some work in `method1` and `method2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if youre calling an async methods to excell.
If so, this is the problem, even though you used locks, the actual calls are running in the same time.
Try to wait till the excell methods ends.
Ofir